# Pandas Multi Index column names

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

How to create a simple dataframe with muli index columns?

```
import pandas as pd

quality = ['strong', 'weak']
types = ['major', 'minor', 'unknown']


import itertools
a = [quality, types]
all_columns = list(itertools.product(*a))

list_ids = ['a1','b2','c3']
df = pd.DataFrame(list_ids, columns = ['ids'])

for col in all_columns:
    df[col] = np.nan
```

now I try to apply `MultiIndex`, but it does not change anything:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(pd.DataFrame(df.columns))
display(df['strong','major'])
```

> KeyError: 'Key length (2) exceeds index depth (1)'

Comment: What is `result_df` here? Also did you mean `pd.MultiIndex.from_product([quality, types])` ?

Comment: sorry. it was mean to be df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas-concat) + [`MultiIndex.from_product`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html#pandas-multiindex-from-product) instead:

```
result_df = pd.concat(
    (df, pd.DataFrame(columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([quality, types]))),
    axis=1
)
```

`result_df`:

```
  ids (strong, major) (strong, minor) (strong, unknown) (weak, major) (weak, minor) (weak, unknown)
0  a1             NaN             NaN               NaN           NaN           NaN             NaN
1  b2             NaN             NaN               NaN           NaN           NaN             NaN
2  c3             NaN             NaN               NaN           NaN           NaN             NaN
```

`result_df['strong', 'major']`:

```
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
Name: (strong, major), dtype: object
```

---

```
import pandas as pd

list_ids = ['a1', 'b2', 'c3']
df = pd.DataFrame(list_ids, columns=['ids'])

quality = ['strong', 'weak']
types = ['major', 'minor', 'unknown']

result_df = pd.concat(
    (df, pd.DataFrame(columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([quality, types]))),
    axis=1
)
```